# How to setup a service from a base module to call a function on a service in a module that uses the base module in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I an writing a service that is to be used in multiple independent websites. However, at some points it needs to trigger different code depending on what website it is used in. I want to keep this per website code separate from the base service.

Here is some example code demonstrating the design I want (although it isn't working):

```js
var baseModule = angular.module('baseModule', []);
baseModule.service('baseService', function() {
    this.func = function() {
        return ["first", 
                /* TODO somehow get from appropriate 
                service in website module */ 
                "FIXME", 
                "end"];
    };
});

var website1 = angular.module('website1', ['baseModule']);
website1.service('website1Service', function() {
    this.someCustomValue = function() { 
        // Note that while this is a constant value, in 
        // the real app it will be more complex,
        // so replacing this service with a constant provider won't work.
        return "someValue"; 
    }
});

// TODO : somehow link website1Service.someCustomValue to baseService

var website2 = angular.module('website2', ['baseModule']);
website2.service('website2Service', function() {
    this.anotherValue = function() { return "anotherValue"; }
});
// TODO : somehow link website2Service.anotherValue to baseService

// Testing code:

function makeTestController(expected) {
    return ['$scope', 'baseService', function($scope, baseService) {
      var result = baseService.func();
  
      if (angular.equals(result, expected)) {
          $scope.outcome = "Test Passed!";
      } else {
          $scope.outcome = 'Test failed...\n' + 
            "Expected: " + angular.toJson(expected) + '\n' +
            "But got : " + angular.toJson(result);
      }
    }];
  }

website1.controller('TestController1', 
                    makeTestController(['first', 'someValue', 'end']));
website2.controller('TestController2', 
                    makeTestController(['first', 'anotherValue', 'end']));

// since this test uses multiple angular apps, bootstrap them manually.
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('website1'), ['website1']);
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('website2'), ['website2']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<h3>Website 1</h3>
<div id='website1'>
  <div ng-controller='TestController1'>
    <pre>{{outcome}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='website2'>
  <h3>Website 2</h3>
  <div ng-controller='TestController2'>
    <pre>{{outcome}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've thought of a few solutions to this, but none seem optimal.

The most obvious way would be to replace the `baseService` service with a provider, and allow it to be configured in each module. This seems to be the standard way of configuring services in other modules. However, I cannot access the `website1Service` and `website2Service` in in the provider functions, as services cannot be accessed in provider functions. This is noted in the docs:

> During application bootstrap, before Angular goes off creating all services, it configures and instantiates all providers. We call this the configuration phase of the application life-cycle. During this phase, services aren't accessible because they haven't been created yet.

Another solution to work around this is use `angular.injector` to find the right service. However, the [docs for `angular.injector`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector) imply that you really only need this for interacting with third party libraries. So it appears there is a better way.

Finally, I could add a dependency to a nonexistant service (eg `"baseServiceActions"`) in `baseModule`, and require a service with that name be implemented in `website1` and `website2`. The dependency injection should then bind it all together when `baseService` is used. However, this is a pretty weird way of working, and would result in poor error messages if the `baseServiceActions` module wasn't implemented in a new website that used the `baseModule` module.

Is there a better way of doing this? If so, is it possible to change the example code I posted to get all the tests passing? Ideally none of the testing code should be changed.

Comment: I really don't get why you dislike the third option when there is a reference to abstract service. It should have same name and public interface and it should be implemented in each module. Is there ability for the `baseService` to work without website implemented service? I mean do you need to have a default `webSiteService`? The error message will be very clear. Missing dependency

Comment: There isn't a way for `baseService` to work without this "abstract service". In my real app, the service the base service needs will handle login ui and notification ui, which are done in different ways in each website. I'm not opposed to this method if it is the standard way of solving this problem, but I just haven't read a single docs page/blog post referencing this technique, so I assumed there must be a better way.

Comment: It is not a standard problem. The standard way would be to create a standalone package (bower/npm). Thus the only communication between this service and your app(s) will be via callbacks or events

Answer (score 0):

I eventually worked out a fairly good solution to this. I created a service named `"<serviceName>Settings"`, and added a `setup` function to it. I then call that setup function in a module run block in the module I want to use it in. Finally I have a `validate` method that is called in the service that uses the settings to ensure it is setup, and throws a nice error message if it isn't. This solved all the problems I had with the other solutions.

This is how my example problem would look with this solution:

```js
var baseModule = angular.module('baseModule', []);
baseModule.service('baseService', ['baseServiceSettings', function(baseServiceSettings) {
    baseServiceSettings.validate();
    this.func = function() {
        return ["first", 
                baseServiceSettings.getValue(),
                "end"];
    };
}]);
baseModule.service('baseServiceSettings', function() {
   this.setup = function(getter) {
      this.getValue = getter;
   };
  this.validate = function() {
    if (!this.getValue) {
      throw "baseServiceSettings not setup! Run baseServiceSettings.setup in a module run block to fix";
    }
  };
});


var website1 = angular.module('website1', ['baseModule']);
website1.run(['baseServiceSettings', 'website1Service', function(baseServiceSettings, website1Service) {
  baseServiceSettings.setup(website1Service.someCustomValue);
}]);
  
  
website1.service('website1Service', function() {
    this.someCustomValue = function() { 
        // Note that while this is a constant value, in 
        // the real app it will be more complex,
        // so replacing this service with a constant provider won't work.
        return "someValue"; 
    }
});


var website2 = angular.module('website2', ['baseModule']);
website2.service('website2Service', function() {
    this.anotherValue = function() { return "anotherValue"; }
});
website2.run(['baseServiceSettings', 'website2Service', function(baseServiceSettings, website2Service) {
  baseServiceSettings.setup(website2Service.anotherValue);
}]);


// Testing code:

function makeTestController(expected) {
    return ['$scope', 'baseService', function($scope, baseService) {
      var result = baseService.func();
  
      if (angular.equals(result, expected)) {
          $scope.outcome = "Test Passed!";
      } else {
          $scope.outcome = 'Test failed...\n' + 
            "Expected: " + angular.toJson(expected) + '\n' +
            "But got : " + angular.toJson(result);
      }
    }];
  }

website1.controller('TestController1', 
                    makeTestController(['first', 'someValue', 'end']));
website2.controller('TestController2', 
                    makeTestController(['first', 'anotherValue', 'end']));

// since this test uses multiple angular apps, bootstrap them manually.
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('website1'), ['website1']);
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('website2'), ['website2']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<h3>Website 1</h3>
<div id='website1'>
  <div ng-controller='TestController1'>
    <pre>{{outcome}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='website2'>
  <h3>Website 2</h3>
  <div ng-controller='TestController2'>
    <pre>{{outcome}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```